# ¿Cómo recorrer arreglo bidimensional en Jquery y evitar un UNDEFINED?

Tags: php, jquery

En **PHP** tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function getUDS(){
    $idSession = $this->session->userdata("userId");
    $res = $this->Home_model->getUDS($idSession);
    $getCount= $this->Home_model->getCountData($idSession);     
    $response = array('make' => $res,'total' => $getCount);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

En **make** estoy enviando un *COUNT* de `SQL` de tareas hechas por **UNIDAD DE NEGOCIO** y en **total** un *COUNT* de tareas existente, es decir: (Ejemplo)

> Hechas: 4 / 5 (Hechas 4 tareas de 5)

**PROBLEMA**

En `jQuery` al momento de recorrer el `JSON` lo recorre 4 veces arrojándome valores **UNDEFINED** *(y son unicamente 2 UDS que existen)*

**(Grafica UNDEFINED)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen representa como debería de quedar, pues esos números (5 Y 1) hacen parte de la misma unidad de negocio representada.

**JQUERY**

```
  var res = $.parseJSON(data);
     $.each(res , function( index, obj ) {                          
     $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
      $(".row").append(`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="card card-stats" >
        <div class="card-content">
         <h3 class="title">${value.groupDescription}</h3>
        </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <i class="material-icons text-success">done_all</i>
           <a href="#" style='color: gray;'>Hecho: ${value.make} / 
           ${value.total}</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
    }); 
});
```

**DATOS PETICIÓN**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un duda, ¿Por qué el uso de dos bucles? para mi lógica estás recorriendo un array que posee un objeto con dos parámetros.

Comment: Si estás haciendo una sola petición Ajax, ¿Qué resultado obtienes? Porque, por lo que se ve, sólo debieses obtener un objeto `{make: x, total:y}` y no un array de 4 objetos con esa estructura.

Comment: Ok, ese es el problema que tengo 2 arreglos distintos en un objecto y quizás por eso me recorre el arreglo 4 veces, ya publicare lo que me esta trayendo la petición para que sea  un poco mas entendible el problema.

Comment: @Edu3D, Hola, el arreglo lo recorro 2 veces ya que como bien tu dices tiene 2 parametros, pero cada parametro es un arreglo mas, entonces lo recorro dos veces para tratar de sacar los parametros o valores de cada arreglo, el problema esta, en que el recorre el arreglo 4 veces para tomar los valores de cada arreglo pero visualmente se ve mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te añado un ejemplo funcional con datos a fuego, para que veas como podrías recorrerlo con un bucle. Tienes que tener en la mente que estás tratando un array con objetos en vez de un array de arrays.

```js
var make = [{
  make: "4",
  groupId: "1",
  groupDescription: "personal"
}, {
  make: "1",
  groupId: "2",
  groupDescription: "Colegio"
}];
var total = [{
  total: "5",
  groupDescription: "personal"
}, {
  total: "1",
  groupDescription: "Colegio"
}];

var res = {
  make,
  total
};
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(res).length; i++) {
  $(".row").append(`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="card card-stats" >
        <div class="card-content">
         <h3 class="title">${res.make[i].groupDescription}</h3>
        </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <i class="material-icons text-success">done_all</i>
           <a href="#" style='color: gray;'>Hecho: ${res.make[i].make} / 
           ${res.total[i].total}</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente @Edu3D, Muchisimas Gracias. Un Saludo.

Comment: Hola @Edu3D, Mira tengo una pregunta y espero puedas colaborarme, te lo agradecería bastante, tengo un incoveniente y es el siguiente, los datos del arreglo ya no tienen la misma longitud, es decir make tiene mas datos que total. como los podria recorrer? gracias

Comment: Hola @JDavid, fíjate como se están accediendo a los datos de *make* y *total*. Solo tienes que acceder a los datos de la misma forma

Answer (score 0):

Estas recorriendo tu bucle interior de jQuery 4 veces, dos por cada una de las 2 veces que recorres el exterior.
Aparte el código PHP que has puesto, no puede funcionar:

```
public function getUDS(){
    $idSession = $this->session->userdata("userId");
    $res = $this->Home_model->getUDS($idSession);

    $getCountNotCheck = $this->Home_model->getCountData($idSession);

    $response = array('make' => $res,'total' => $getCount);

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Estas guardando una variable no definida en el array response: `$getCount`. Supongo que la que quieres guardar es `$getCountNotCheck`. Recibirías una notificación:

> Notice:  Undefined variable...

Activa los errores de PHP durante el desarrollo.

Comment: Hola @Orici gracias por responder, si, he visto que he cometido un error en la variable de php pero fue un error al momento de digitar para preguntar... ya editare la pregunta y pondré lo que me trae la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos objetos pero recorres el array 4 veces? no entiendo.

De todas maneras, si lo que quieres reconocer cuando una variable es `undefined` aqui te dejo

```
if(typeof VARIABLE === "undefined") {
  // Tu codigo va aqui...
}
```

Comment: Hola @Anthony Gracias por responder, ya intente ese método pero no me funciono, quizás no me he hecho entender con el problema y es mi error, pero se esta recorriendo 4 veces porque los dos objectos están trayendo 2 arreglos CADA uno, en la imagen de la petición se muestra.